# Elementary runs smoothly from usb but lags after installation

Tags: release-freya, system-installation, graphic-drivers, hardware

I recently installed elementary os freya 0.3.1 . At first , when I tried it from usb , the os ran smoothly considering it wasnt a native install. However, after I installed it ,it lagged pretty bad! Files took forever to load and close and graphics were really choppy. Plus, the fan wouldnt slow down and made noise the whole time. I tried installing the nvidia drivers from the Additional drivers tab but nothing changed . I have a compaq presario cq61 which seems totally compatible ,and every other distro I have tried runs pretty smoothly.Any suggestions?

Comment: I have freya 0.3.1 installed in an USB myself and it runs quite smoothly. I don't have a swap partition, though. That tends to slow the system down if you have enough RAM, besides reducing the lifespan of the USB stick itself. Do you have a swap partition?

Comment: I installed the os using the default options of the installer so I guess it created a swap partition

Comment: You have to use the "Something else" option to install it without swap. After re reading your original post, however, I am not sure: did you mean you installed it in the USB stick? I was assuming that.

Comment: No, i installed it normally. I just tried it before installing from the live usb

Comment: Oh, I see. In that case something else might be happening there. Maybe someone else has experience on this and can add some perspective.

Comment: Same issue here...
Just in case someone got the answer ..

Comment: Is it because that the whole system is copied to the ram while using LiveUSB? Like how ramdisk does.

Comment: Did my answer work

Answer (score 1):

Your hard drive might be slow.Try replacing the hard drive with a new one or an SSD.Slow disk access can make your system slow.The USB does not use the disk but the USB instead so it is faster